# Call a method from a Go template

Tags: go, go-templates

Let's say I have

```
type Person struct {
  Name string
}
func (p *Person) Label() string {
  return "This is " + p.Name
}
```

How can I use this method from a html/template ? I would need something like this in my template:

```
{{ .Label() }}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Just omit the parentheses and it should be fine. Example:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type Person string

func (p Person) Label() string {
    return "This is " + string(p)
}

func main() {
    tmpl, err := template.New("").Parse(`{{.Label}}`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Parse: %v", err)
    }
    tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, Person("Bob"))
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Arguments), you can call any method which returns one value (of any type) or two values if the second one is of type `error`. In the later case, `Execute` will return that error if it is non-nil and stop the execution of the template.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! I had tried it, but the receiver of my method was *Person instead of Person. So it does not work with pointer receivers, that seems to be the catch.

Comment: It also work with pointer receivers. But please note that when you have a `func (p *Person) Label()` only values of the type `*Person` will have a Label() method. You can not call that method on a `Person`, since you haven't defined it.

Comment: And can I write {{ &. }} to get the address of . in my template ?

Comment: No, you can't. But if you define your methods on a `*Person` (which is required if you want to change its attribute), just use `*Person`s all the time.

Comment: This is so much cleaner than [template.Funcs(FuncMap)](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs)!

Comment: I also found that when I have a method that takes a pointer as an argument, the template let's me pass nil as the argument to the method. Nice.

Answer (score 49):

You can even pass parameters to function like follows

```
type Person struct {
  Name string
}
func (p *Person) Label(param1 string) string {
  return "This is " + p.Name + " - " + param1
}
```

And then in the template write

```
{{with person}}
    {{ .Label "value1"}}
{{end}}
```

Assuming that the person in the template is a variable of type Person passed to Template.

Comment: how do you pass multiple arguments?

Comment: @chovy simply {{ .Label "value1" "value2"}}

Answer (score -2):

Unsure if it is incompetence on my part or a recent change in Go templates, but I am unable to access functions on the data struct passed into Execute. Always receive "`can't evaluate field`" error.

I was able to get this working by using [`FuncMap`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#FuncMap) instead.

Example:

```
temp := template.New("templatename.gohtml")
temp.Funcs(
    template.FuncMap{
        "label": Label,
    },
)
temp, err := temp.ParseFiles(
    "templatename.gohtml",
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error parsing template", err)
}

err = temp.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
```

In template:

```
{{label "the label"}}
```

Label func:

```
func Label(param string) string {
  ...
}
```

Comment: As pointed out by tux21b, make sure your template has a pointer if the method is defined on a pointer, and a non-pointer if the method is defined on a non-pointer.