# Using struct method in Golang template

Tags: go, go-templates

Struct methods in Go templates are usually called same way as public struct properties but in this case it just doesn't work: http://play.golang.org/p/xV86xwJnjA

```
{{with index . 0}}
  {{.FirstName}} {{.LastName}} is {{.SquareAge}} years old.
{{end}}
```

Error:

```
executing "person" at <.SquareAge>: SquareAge is not a field
of struct type main.Person
```

Same problem with:

```
{{$person := index . 0}}
{{$person.FirstName}} {{$person.LastName}} is
  {{$person.SquareAge}} years old.
```

In constrast, this works:

```
{{range .}}
  {{.FirstName}} {{.LastName}} is {{.SquareAge}} years old.
{{end}}
```

How to call SquareAge() method in {{with}} and {{$person}} examples?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call a method from a Go template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200178/call-a-method-from-a-go-template)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As previously answered in [Call a method from a Go template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200178/call-a-method-from-a-go-template), the method as defined by

```
func (p *Person) SquareAge() int {
    return p.Age * p.Age
}
```

is only available on type `*Person`.

Since you don't mutate the `Person` object in the `SquareAge` method, you could just change the receiver from `p *Person` to `p Person`, and it would work with your previous slice.

Alternatively, if you replace

```
var people = []Person{
    {"John", "Smith", 22},
    {"Alice", "Smith", 25},
    {"Bob", "Baker", 24},
}
```

with

```
var people = []*Person{
    {"John", "Smith", 22},
    {"Alice", "Smith", 25},
    {"Bob", "Baker", 24},
}
```

It'll work as well.

Working example #1: http://play.golang.org/p/NzWupgl8Km

Working example #2: http://play.golang.org/p/lN5ySpbQw1

Comment: Surprisingly, the compiler's clever enough to add the `&Person`s for you as long as the slice is declared to be of the right type: http://play.golang.org/p/FsKEUjmxPn