# Access first item of sorted pair list

Tags: templates, go, indexing, range, go-templates

I'm new to Go Templates and I'm trying to access the first element in a `SortedPair` list. I tried `{{ (index .Labels.SortedPairs 1)}}{{ .Name }} = {{ .Value }}` but that's not working, I'm getting `can't evaluate field Name in type template.Alert`.

Is there a way to get the very first element? When it's a `{{range}}`, it works fine but displays too many elements.

Thanks

Comment: You can create a function or method that returns the first pair, and call it from the template. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200178/call-a-method-from-a-go-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the first index is `0` and not `1`.

You may index the list both when displaying its `Name` and `Value`:

```
{{(index .Labels.SortedPairs 0).Name}} = {{(index .Labels.SortedPairs 0).Value}}
```

It's shorter if you assign it to a variable though:

```
{{$first := index .Labels.SortedPairs 0}}{{$first.Name}} = {{$first.Value}}
```

And even clearer if you use the `{{with}}` action:

```
{{with index .Labels.SortedPairs 0}}{{.Name}} = {{.Value}}{{end}}
```

Let's test the 3 variants:

```
type Pair struct {
    Name, Value string
}

var variants = []string{
    `{{$first := index .SortedPairs 0}}{{$first.Name}} = {{$first.Value}}`,
    `{{(index .SortedPairs 0).Name}} = {{(index .SortedPairs 0).Value}}`,
    `{{with index .SortedPairs 0}}{{.Name}} = {{.Value}}{{end}}`,
}

m := map[string]interface{}{
    "SortedPairs": []Pair{
        {"first", "1"},
        {"second", "2"},
    },
}

for _, templ := range variants {
    t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
    if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZXtivqAnZH)):

```
first = 1
first = 1
first = 1
```

Comment: And even clearer if you write simple functions which allow you to write even simpler templates ; )

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Sorry I can't upvote yet, not enough rep